# Overriding subclass functions with different return type

Tags: c++, overriding, virtual-functions

Suppose I have the following implementation:

```
class Number
{
public:
  virtual ??? getValue()
  {
     return 0;
  }
};

class Float: public Number
{
public:
  float getValue()
  {
     return 12.34;
  }
};

class Int: public Number
{
public:
  int getValue()
  {
    return 123;
  }
};
```

And elsewhere:

```
std::map<std::string,Number*> numberMap; // Assume initialized with some list

float f = numberMap["someFloat"]->getValue();
int i = numberMap["someInt"]->getValue();
```

As the bottom code section shows, I'd like to call getValue() without downcasting. Is this possible, and if so, how would I set up the class definitions?

Comment: co-variant return type is for polymorphic class, here you cannot do that.

Comment: How does `numberMap["someFloat"]` know that it is a `Float`, and therefore know to use `getValue` from inside `Float`?  All that it knows is that it is a `Number*`.  Therefore you need a cast somewhere (with this design, at least).

Comment: This seems more a case for a tagged union type. Try `boost::variant` for instance.

Comment: @0x5453 Yes, I understand. I'm asking for the particular situation that I have, how can I better design this?

Comment: @statguy If all you need is special handling for `Number::getvalue`, you could template `getValue` on the desired return type and then cast your value or overload the function to do the conversion.  If you need to have the dedicated subclasses, I would look into `variant`s like @StoryTeller suggested.